# What is the purpose of this package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL. I have found this package and it is called from a trigger. I just cannot figure exactly what this simple looking package code is doing.

It is called from a trigger as below:

```
IF INSERTING THEN
        i := STATE_PKG_OVERRIDE_CN.AffectedRows.COUNT+1;
        STATE_PKG_OVERRIDE_CN.AffectedRows(i).IDU := :new.IDU;
        STATE_PKG_OVERRIDE_CN.AffectedRows(i).cn := :new.cn;
```

This is the package. Can somebody please explain the basics of what is it doing? does it return a value? change a value? what is AffectedRows RIDARRAY or EMPTY ?

```
create or replace PACKAGE        STATE_PKG_OVERRIDE_CN
AS
   TYPE rowid_cn IS RECORD
        (
        idu     dirxml.USR.IDU%TYPE,
        cn      dirxml.USR.CN%TYPE
        );

     TYPE RIDARRAY IS TABLE OF rowid_cn INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

        AffectedRows RIDARRAY;
        EMPTY   RIDARRAY;
END;
```

I have googled EMPTY but found nothing, i believe it is creating a table of type record. The trigger is passing in a value of cn or IDU am i am familiar with these two values. But what is the package doing? or returning ? im confused.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is a bespoke package belonging to your organisation. (That's why Google wasn't helpful for you.) We cannot tell you for sure what it does or how it's used. But we can guess.

The package has no procedures or functions, it just defines array variables of a bespoke type, which can be used by other program units such as triggers. The trigger you posted assigns values to the array `AffectedRows`. Presumably this trigger fires FOR EACH ROW. Likely there is another trigger on the same table firing AFTER STATEMENT which reads that array and does some processing, then assigns `AffectedRows := EMPTY` to reset the array.

The purpose of this infrastructure is to pass state across trigger actions. A common reason for doing this is work around a mutating table exception. They are risky because state cannot be guaranteed; for instance if a insert fails before the AFTER STATEMENT trigger fires the `AffectedRows` array is not re-initialised, so subsequent processing will be incorrect (or will fail).

Since 11g Oracle provides compound triggers which remove the need for this sort of package. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005).

To investigate further, first you want to check USER_TRIGGERS to find other triggers on the table which owns the trigger you mentioned. If that doesn't help or you want to see whether other tables also use this package run this query:

```
select * 
from user_dependencies
where referenced_type = 'PACKAGE'
and referenced_name = 'STATE_PKG_OVERRIDE_CN'
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly the reason. We have a similar package, but ours contains multiple lists like that for various triggers (because triggers can update other stuff that fires other triggers... ikr!). This leads (amongst other issues) to deployment hell because they all become invalid if you try to add a list for a new usecase. Compound triggers are definitely the way to go here, and we're slowly phasing out the supporting package

Answer (score 0):

It begins with the package which

- declares a type `ROWID_CN` as a record that contains two values: `IDU` and `CN`
- syntax requires to create another type (`RIDARRAY`) which is based on previously declared `ROWID_CN`
- `affectedrows` and `empty` are *arrays* whose type is `RIDARRAY`. Basically, you can imagine them as a table that has two columns, `IDU` and `CN`

Now, a trigger: piece of code you posted says that those 3 lines are executed when someone inserts a row into a table the trigger is based on. For example,

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_emp 
  before insert or update on emp
  for each row
declare
  i number;
begin
  if inserting then ...
```

Apparently, there's some code that is executed when *updating*, or even *deleting* rows.

Anyway:

- `i := ...` line counts number of elements in `affectedrows` array (which is declared in the package) and adds `1` to that number. For example, if there were `3` elements, `i` would be `4`.
- `...affectedrows(i).idu := :new.idu` enters a new *row* into the array. Its ordinal number is `i` (`4` in our example). As you're inserting a row into the table, trigger knows `IDU` column's `:new` value and puts it into the array. For example, if you used

  ```
  insert into emp (idu, cn) values (100, 'A')
  ```

  then `affectedrows(4).idu = 100`, while `affectedrows(4).cn = 'A'`

It is, probably, something similar with `EMPTY` array. Google can't return anything *useful*, it is just a custom-made array.